# Problems with ggplot background when arranging more than one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2` and making an arrange using `ggarange` to make some graphs but when I save them using `ggsave` the background appears in black and the axis names are not visible. This doesn't happen if I export the plots arraged by using the export button of `RStudio`. Any idea of why can this happen? Here is the code

```
library(ggplot2)

col<-c("#F8766D", "#619CFF","#00BA38")

fine<-(rep(c("Fischer-like","Medium","Lewis-like"),each=2))
fine
sex<-rep(c("Males","Females"), times=3)

prop<-c(0.41*100,0.59*100,0.65*100,0.35*100,0.45*100,0.55*100)

etapa_a<-data.frame(fine,sex,prop)
etapa_a

a<-ggplot(data=etapa_a, aes(x=sex,y=prop))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=fine),width = 0.5,color = "black") + theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("#F8766D", "#619CFF","#00BA38"),
                    limits = c("Fischer-like","Medium",  "Lewis-like"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text((colour="black"),size= 15),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())

a<-a+labs(x=" Sex",y="")+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))+
  geom_text(aes(y = prop,x=sex, label = prop, group =fine), 
            color = "black", 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),size=8)

a

prop<-c(0.13*100,0.86*100,0.78*100,0.22*100,0.54*100,0.45*100)

etapa_b<-data.frame(fine,sex,prop)
etapa_b

b<-ggplot(data=etapa_b, aes(x=sex,y=prop))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=fine),width = 0.5,color = "black") + theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("#F8766D", "#619CFF","#00BA38"),
                    limits = c("Fischer-like","Medium",  "Lewis-like"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text((colour="black"),size= 15),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())

b<-b+labs(x=" Sex",y="")+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))+
  geom_text(aes(y = prop,x=sex, label = prop, group =fine), 
            color = "black", 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),size=8)

b

prop<-c(0.26*100,0.73*100,0.48*100,0.51*100,0.78*100,0.22*100)

etapa_c<-data.frame(fine,sex,prop)
etapa_c

c<-ggplot(data=etapa_c, aes(x=sex,y=prop))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=fine),width = 0.5,color = "black") + theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("#F8766D", "#619CFF","#00BA38"),
                    limits = c("Fischer-like","Medium",  "Lewis-like"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text((colour="black"),size= 15),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())

c<-c+labs(x=" Sex",y="")+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))+
  geom_text(aes(y = prop,x=sex, label = prop, group =fine), 
            color = "black", 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),size=8)

c

prop<-c(0.16*100,0.84*100,0.89*100,0.11*100,0.51*100,0.48*100)

etapa_d<-data.frame(fine,sex,prop)
etapa_d

d<-ggplot(data=etapa_d, aes(x=sex,y=prop))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=fine),width = 0.5,color = "black") + theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("#F8766D", "#619CFF","#00BA38"),
                    limits = c("Fischer-like","Medium",  "Lewis-like"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text((colour="black"),size= 15),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())

d<-d+labs(x=" Sex",y="")+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))+
  geom_text(aes(y = prop,x=sex, label = prop, group =fine), 
            color = "black", 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),size=8)

d

library(ggpubr)
library(grid)

prop_sex <- ggarrange(a + rremove("ylab") + rremove("xlab"),b + rremove("ylab") 
                  + rremove("xlab"), c + rremove("ylab") + rremove("xlab"), 
                  d + rremove("ylab") + rremove("xlab"), # remove axis labels from plots
                  labels = c("A", "B", "C","D"),label.x = -0.01,
                  ncol = 1, nrow = 4,
                  common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom",
                  align = "hv", 
                  font.label = list(size = 9, color = "black", face = "bold",
                                    family = NULL, position = "top"))

prop_sex<-annotate_figure(prop_sex, left = textGrob("Percentage of individuals", 
                                                         rot = 90, vjust = 1, 
                                            gp = gpar(cex = 1.3),(vjust=-0.02)),
                      bottom = textGrob("", gp = gpar(cex = 1.3)))

prop_sex

ggsave(filename = "test1.jpg", plot = last_plot(),
       path = "C:/Users/Usuario/Dropbox/Inmunoneuro/uno_a_uno/plots_multivar",
       width=15,height =30,units="cm",
       dpi = 300)
```

I am attaching the plots. Test1 is th one saved using `ggsave` and test2 is the one exported from the `export` button from `RStudio`[[image: Test1Test2]

Comment: I'm having an error creating your first plot `a`. Can you get this issue in a **minimal** example so we can easily reproduce it? I tried a simple example and had no issue with the `ggsave` version.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue on my Mac when exporting to png via `ggsave`. This is also a known issue which in my case could be fixed by setting the `bg` color using e.g. `ggsave(..., bg = "white")`. Also note that IMHO you can simplify your code considerably by binding your datasets into one df and using facetting. But that's a different matter.